# asp.net It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineOnly' beyond machine.config

Tags: asp.net, machine.config

Hey guys i've been trying to upload my website to a remote server, but i keep getting this error. i have changed every 'allowDefinition' to 'Everywhere' in two machine configs, but i did not help. It highlights ' deployment retail="true"/ ' as the problem field. Any help will be appreciated.

Full error description:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineOnly' beyond machine.config.

Source Error:

```
Line 23:     </compilation>
Line 24:       <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"></customErrors>
Line 25:       ***<deployment retail="true"/>***
Line 26:       <trace mostRecent="true" enabled="true" requestLimit="1000" pageOutput="false"                 localOnly="true"/>
Line 27:     <authentication mode="Forms" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228298%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the **deployment** element can ONLY be set at the machine level.

Comment: Jason, where does MSDN state that deployment can't be set at application level? Override can be enabled in machine.config.

Comment: on the linked page, "This value can only be set at the machine level, not at the application level."

Comment: I see, didn't notice when I first looked. Maybe it's stating that applies to all applications, however it definitely can be set in application level web.config files too depending on the value of allowDefinition attribute in machine.config: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228245(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a virtual directory. In VS, go to project properties and select the Web tab. There, you will find a button to create it. Leave the machine.config files alone unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

My fix was that I edited machine.config and deleted allowDefinition attribute from the declaration of deployment element. I don't claim this is the recommended fix. Note that there are more machine.config files for different .Net versions and also for x86 and x64 applications.
I.e.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
```